# Disable PHP count?

Tags: php

So, I am trying to modify a piece of code that I have, it is a calendar that is used for taking reservations. I am posting events on the calendar that users will be able to book by clicking on the link on any given day.  It currently allows me to only post 2 events for booking, on any given day.  These 2 cannot be at the exact same time.   I want to change that, I need it to be able to post multiple spots available at the exact same time.  For example, if it is a martial arts class and there are 10 open spots, it should show 10 spots available at the same time of day...  You get the point...

I believe this is what is preventing me from achieving that, but im not certain...

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks is advance.

```
<script>
    <?php
    if($numslots>0) {
        ?>
        alert('<?php echo $numslots; ?> slots added');
        <?php
    } else if($numslots == -1) {
        ?>
        alert('Days selected are holidays. Cannot make these changes');
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        alert('Duplicate slots. Cannot make these changes');
        <?php
    }
    ?>

    document.location.href="calendar_manage.php?calendar_id=<?php echo $_GET["calendar_id"]; ?>&ref=slots";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, where you have ten slots available for one time, you need to populate a new variable.. lets call it $available_slots.. you need to populate this with the number of slots, in this case ten. So you would end up with ...

```
$available_slots = 10;

if($numslots<$available_slots) {
    ?>
    alert('<?php echo $numslots; ?> slots added');
    <?php
} else if($numslots == -1) {
   etc...
```

Notice the first if condition.. we now check if $numslots is **less** than $available_slots, rather than **greater** than zero.

Comment: Well, that didn't work.. I don't understand, in the original is says if $numslots>0  = slots added...  wouldnt the $numslots always be greater than 0 ?  so why can i only add 2?

Comment: My mistake, I have corrected my answer.. the if condition should check if your $numslots are less than your available_slots. Try with that.

Comment: Ok.  Now I'm getting a "0 slots added" response, better than "Duplicate Slots, cannot make these changes"

I assume there is somewhere else in the code that is preventing a new slot from being created..  (not the code i uploaded here, the entire .php file)

Comment: Change the "Duplicate Slots" message to read something else to confirm if it is coming from the IF you showed us, it probably is not being overwritten elsewhere. Double check the value of $numslots and $available_slots by printing them out immediately before your IF statement code.